# nginx conditional redirects rules

Tags: redirect, nginx, nginx-location

I have such a task:
http://www.realtyadvisorselite.com/homes-for-sale/skokie
to redirect permanently to 
http://www.realtyadvisorselite.com/residential/homes-for-sale/skokie

another words add "residential" subfolder if it is missing from url
I have such server blocks in nginx.conf

```
        server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  realtyadvisorselite.com;
        return       301     http://www.realtyadvisorselite.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.realtyadvisorselite.com;
    location / {
          proxy_pass http://repar;
    }
}
```

Sorry, seems like a simple task but I cannot understand nginx regexp approach... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You question implies that it is a single URL that requires redirection. So a simple option is to use an exact match location and a return statement:

```
location = /homes-for-sale/skokie {
    return 301 /residential/homes-for-sale/skokie;
}
```

If you wanted all URIs that begin with `/homes-for-sale` to be prefixed with `/residential`, you could use a prefix location and a return statement:

```
location ^~ /homes-for-sale/ {
    return 301 /residential$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: thank you, Richard. But in 99 cases it is accessed with residential/homes-for-sale. Would not it redirect to residential/residential/homes-for-sale/....?

Comment: No. URIs beginning with `/residential` would not match the `location` blocks above, and would be processed by your existing `location /` block, as per normal.